# Set datetimepicker max/min values while loading

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using a modified version of [vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker) which is a vue component wrapper for [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker).

I have two inputs: a start date and an end date. When I set the end date, it sets this value to the max-value of the start date, and when I change the start date, it sets this value to the min-value of the end date.

All works well when I change the values, but for pre-loaded values I can't find a way to set the min/max values.

In this fiddle I have all the needed code http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/xhqrdm0t/

I tried some things:

- Triggering `dp.change` after values are loaded: `$(".dpdatainicio, .dpdatafim").trigger("dp.change");` - Result: For some reason the values are reset to blank.
- Changing the order the component is initialized - Result: Doesn't work because when start date gets initialized end date isn't yet.

So how could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As [the guide which introduces options](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/) for **bootstrap-datetimepicker**, uses option property=minDate and maxDate to limit min/max date for initial.

So your new **datepickoptions** will be like:

```
   datepickoptions: {
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    useCurrent: false,
    locale: 'pt-br',
    minDate: '2018-10-09', // min date value
    maxDate: '2018-10-29'  // max date value
  },
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhqrdm0t/4/)